# Better management of "messages" between function?

Tags: php, frameworks

I my framework I have some functions that when done they can add some messages to a queue for reporting.

Example: I have a function that takes a path of a photo and

- if the image is not .jpg it converts it to .jpg
- if the image is greater than 500kB it reduces its size

I have a global `$msgQueue=array();` and whenever all the logic of the page is done, in my template I echo to the users all the reports (that the functions could add during the exectuion).

In that case 2 messages would be added to $msgQueue:

- The image was PNG and has been converted to JPG
- The image was 2000x1000 and now is 1000x500

But this kind of behaviour I think it's not standard. If I want share with someone one of my function (in this case is `checkImage($path)`) It can't work because the functions needs that global array to put their report msgs.

Is there a standard approach to solve this so I can share my functions with someone else and don't worry about this dependence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use a class, something like:

```
class Report(){
    public $msgQueue;

    function addReport($string){ 
         array_push($this->msgQueue, $string);  //store new report
    }

    function showReports(){
         //loop over the message queue
         ...
    }
}
```

**Benefits:**

1. You could have different kind of reports using the same class, separating process from errors for example, `$processes = new Report` and `$errors = new Report`
2. No need to declare vars as globals, the class preserves the value of its property `$msgQueue` you would only need to `$processes->addReport("Resizing image to XXX")`
3. The benefits of OOP, having a logical structure, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think there is a standard approach.  What I do is this:

- Give each library (Image, File, etc..) its own message array.
- Use a Message library that has its own message array as well as an array of "sources" that can be built/added to via `Message::addSource($class, $propertyName)`.  (I add a message source right after I make an instance of a library, such as Image).

  - When Message::render() is executed, it combines each source's messages with the *Message* class's own message then renders them.

Doing it that way allows each library to be independent of others while still being able have both a per-instance and global message array.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a standard approach to solve
>   this?

Yes, its called [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) :) (see [amosrivera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519521/better-management-of-messages-between-function/5519593#5519593)'s answer for that).

But if OOP is not an option (but you should seriously consider it nonetheless), then refactoring the functions to accept a messageQueue argument (and passing it by reference) might work.

```
// passing $messageQueue by reference by prepending &
function checkImage( $path, array &$messageQueue = null )
{
    /* do image checking */
    $result = /* the result of the image checking */;

    // if $messageQueue argument is provided
    if( $messageQueue !== null )
    {
        // add the message to the queue
        $messageQueue[] = 'Image checking done';
    }

    return $result; // false or true perhaps.
}
```

Usage:

```
$messageQueue = array();

if( checkImage( $somePath, $messageQueue ) )
{
    echo 'checking image succeeded';
}
else
{
    echo 'checking image failed';
}

var_dump( $messageQueue );

// would output something like:
Array(1) (
    'Image checking done'
)
```

Comment: that's almost what I do now, but yes maybe building an Object as Message is the solution here